# Extra HDD or hybrid SSD for my Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an SSD installed on my laptop and currently it boots 4 Operating Systems. I have my old HDD installed but it is low on capacity. I want to increase the capacity by buying another HDD. I see the options available are 1TB or more HDD or 750 GB hybrid. My question is, if I already have an SSD as a primary drive, does buying an extra hybrid ssd make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this for fact... but... I don't think a hybrid drive will be of any benefit. I have a hybrid drive in my Mac and it was a huge increase in performance, but what it did was simply cache my most used items. Since your primary drive is a full SSD, this is already done.

I would go with a normal HDD.